# Jurisdiction of Swedish Administrative Court for non-resident

Tags: sweden

Plaintiff P. wants to sue a Swedish government agency over an incorrect administrative order.

Usually, jurisdiction would be where P. lives; However, P. doesn't live in Sweden (and never did).

Now which förvaltningsrätt has jurisdiction? Possible options would be:

a) P. needs to figure out which part of the country has the strongest connection to the case and sue there

b) Jurisdiction is at the seat of the foreign ministry

c) Jurisdiction is at the headquarter of the defendant

d) The case is subject to flying jurisdiction

e) Jurisdiction is where plaintiff spent his last summer vacation

f) Jurisdiction is to be determined by the judge

g) Jurisdiction is in Stockholm

h) something else

Comment: I would think that it would be depend upon the nature of the dispute. Also, if P. filed on place and got it wrong, the remedy would probably be for the government to file a motion for change of venue to transfer the case to the right court. So the down side to getting it wrong is probably modest.

Comment: All Swedish administrative orders I've seen contain information about how to proceed